# How to understand below ant task definition

Tags: ant, build.xml

I have questions about below ant knowledge.

1. What's the meaning of ***resource*** in ***taskdef*** tag?
2. What do ant-tasks.jar do?
3. What does it do about below?

My understanding is that, ant-tasks.jar executes to load android.jar and other relative jars, is that right?

```
<!-- jar file from where the tasks are loaded --> 
<path id="android.antlibs">
    <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/ant-tasks.jar" /> 
</path>

<!-- Custom tasks --> 
<taskdef resource="anttasks.properties" classpathref="android.antlibs" />
```

Comment: aliteralmind, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---*What's the meaning of resource in taskdef tag?*

Look here, under "parameters":

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/typedef.html

---*What does it do about below?*

This

```
 <taskdef resource="anttasks.properties" classpathref="android.antlibs" />
```

is replaced with this

```
<taskdef resource="anttasks.properties" classpathref="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/ant-tasks.jar" />
```

---*What do ant-tasks.jar do?*

It's a zip file containing custom-built ant tasks (add-ons), which you could use in your `build.xml`. Find out who made it, or where to find its JavaDoc.